# TCPDF Font Directory error, wrong directory separators

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf, directory-structure

Hi i'm just integrated CodeIgniter with PHPWord seamlessly and working with no problem, but at the moment to integrate TCPDF gives me an error like this:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: opendir(C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\PTC\application\third_party\tcpdf/fonts/,C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\PTC\application\third_party\tcpdf/fonts/): El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.(Translated: The system can not find the file specified .) (code: 2)

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 4154
```

The first thing i saw is the wrong directory separators (some PHP libraries has the same issue when is used in non-UNIX enviroments as Windows, using hardcoded directory separators).

I've modified the php files with the PHP constant: DIRECTORY SEPARATOR but with no luck. Some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various paths you can/must set in the TCPDF config file `./config/tcpdf_config.php`.

For example, there's a `K_PATH_FONTS` constant which sets the path to the fonts, maybe you also need/want to set `K_PATH_MAIN`.

Comment: Well that's explains everything, instead to going deep to the source. thanks.

Comment: TCPDF is a bit weird in its structure and coding. But in the end it's a versatile and stable working library, so you just have to work around those few quirks. ;)